# Problems with unstable wireless (Ralink RT5392)

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, drivers, ralink

I am having trouble fixing an unusably slow wireless network on a new PC with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed.
After a while I have no network connection. It works if I restart my computer (still slow), but the connection usually becomes slower and later on I am unable to use it.

The wireless card I am using is a D-Link DWA-548 pci-express.

I came accross a couple of simular issues in my googling research, none of the suggestions helped me.

Here are some useful commands printing out information that may help. I have seen some of the gurus asked for this info (got it from one of varunendra's posts.):

Code:

```
====================================================================================
lsb_release -d
--------------
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

====================================================================================
uname -mr
---------
3.13.0-55-generic x86_64


====================================================================================
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
--------------------------
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
        Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Motherboard [1458:e000]
        Kernel driver in use: r8169
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT5392 PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [1814:5392]
        Subsystem: D-Link System Inc Device [1186:3c06]
        Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci


====================================================================================
lsmod
-----
Module                  Size  Used by
...
rt2800pci              13598  0 
rt2800mmio             20986  1 rt2800pci
rt2800lib              88867  2 rt2800pci,rt2800mmio
rt2x00pci              13287  1 rt2800pci
rt2x00mmio             13603  2 rt2800pci,rt2800mmio
rt2x00lib              55250  5 rt2x00pci,rt2800lib,rt2800pci,rt2800mmio,rt2x00mmio
mac80211              639514  3 rt2x00lib,rt2x00pci,rt2800lib
cfg80211              541326  2 mac80211,rt2x00lib
r8169                  67581  0
...


====================================================================================
iwconfig
--------
eth0      no wireless extensions.


lo        no wireless extensions.


wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"xx xxx"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: <masked_address>  
          Bit Rate=27 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=47/70  Signal level=-63 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:37  Invalid misc:125   Missed beacon:0


====================================================================================
rfkill list all
---------------
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no


====================================================================================
iw reg get
----------
country 00:
        (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
        (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
        (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
        (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
        (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS


====================================================================================
nm-tool
-------
NetworkManager Tool


State: connected (global)


- Device: wlan0  [Ex Mente]
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            rt2800pci
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <masked_address>


  Capabilities:
    Speed:           14 Mb/s


  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes


  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
    *Ex Mente:       Infra, <masked_address>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 57 WPA2


  IPv4 Settings:
  .
  .
  .



- Device: eth0
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <masked_address>


  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes


  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off

====================================================================================
sudo iwlist scan
----------------
eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlan0     Scan completed :
      Cell 01 - Address: <masked_address>
                Channel:1
                Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                Quality=53/70  Signal level=-57 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"Ex Mente"
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                          24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                Mode:Master
                Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                Extra: Last beacon: 56ms ago
                IE: Unknown: 00084578204D656E7465
                IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                IE: Unknown: 030101
                IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                IE: Unknown: 2F0104
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : CCMP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                IE: Unknown: 2D1AFE181BFFFF000001000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: 3D1601051700000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: DD7D0050F204104A00011010440001021041000100103B00010310470010550364D39CAC0C7C62E4DD6D11DFF2AD102100074E6574676561721023000944474E3232303076331024000944474E32323030763310420004313233341054000800060050F20400011011000944474E323230307633100800020084103C000101
                IE: Unknown: DD090010180205F02C0000
                IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00


====================================================================================
egrep '^(#.*device|[^#]|$)' /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
---------------------------------------------------------------------
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<masked_address>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"


# PCI device 0x1814:0x5392 (rt2800pci)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<masked_address>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"


====================================================================================
dmesg | grep 'wlan|rt2'
-----------------------
```

I tried to set the nohwcrypt as well, but had no success:

Code:

```
sudo modprobe -rv rt2800pci
sudo modprobe -v rt2800pci nohwcrypt=Y
```

It leaves my wireless unable to connect.